# Getting more than one value using return in execute_script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying access js variables from a website and I am doing something like this:

```
log = driver.execute_script(""" return v1,v2; """)
print log
```

where `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

It is returning only the value for `v2` variable but not the `v1`.

Is there any way I can return more than one variable and store it into a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the values with brackets

```
log = driver.execute_script(""" return [v1, v2]; """)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried using `return (v1,v2);` earlier but that didn't work, any thoughts ?

Comment: Okay, got it javascript doesn't support that. Thanks again.